# Qt QML MapRoute line is not very well constructed, flickering

Tags: qt, qml, maps, qtlocation

I am trying to develop a navigation application with Qt and Qt location plugins. Right now, I am testing using Here plugin. 
Since the Map plugin allows me to set up tilt, bearing, zoomLevel etc. I am well able to do what I am trying to do, except with a flaw in the line that is constructed by RouteModel and MapRoute that is viewed on the screen. The following is how I am able to display the route:

```
       MapItemView {
            model: routeModel
            delegate:  Component {
                MapRoute {
                    route: routeData
                    line.color: "#d0021b"
                    line.width: 7
                    antialiasing: true
                    smooth: true
                }
            }
        }
```

As I increase the zoom level and take a closer look at the route, I can see that the route flickers, and on some parts even not very well displayed.

An example of this situation is as follows:
[image: Flawed case]
[image: Alternative link]

I could see that the picture corrects itself and the flickering stops if I change zoomLevel from around 18 to 10. But this is not what I want since I want the navigation feel. I am looking for better ways to draw this route, simply.

I don't know how to solve this problem and I would appreciate if I could get some advice. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Added an alternative link to the image

**EDIT2:** I tried with both Qt 5.8.0 and Qt 5.10.1, with Here map plugin. Step to reproduce would be getting a route map from Dortmund,Germany to Izmir,Turkey, and zooming in with zoomLevel 18, 19 or 20 at Königswall street. (This flickering happens in many occasions, this is just one example to reproduce)

Comment: Link to the image - 403 Forbidden

Comment: @folibis Could you try once more? If not valid still, I'll use a different image upload service.

Comment: you should write what version of Qt, and steps to reproduce, since the parameters of your image are unknown. The best you could do is filing a bug report on bugreports.qt.io

Comment: @Pa_ I have updated the question